# jQuery change css by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, indexing

I want to change the css of an element by jQuery index.

```js
 $(".switcher span").click(function() {
   var galleryIndex = $(this).index();
   $('.wrapper .gallery').eq(galleryIndex).css("background", "red");
 });
```

```html
<div class="switcher">
  <span>Switch 0</span>
  <span>Switch 1</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">GALLERY 0</div>
  <div class="gallery">GALLERY 1</div>
</div>
```

jQuery gets the index of the `.switcher span` fine but it seems that the index pf the gallery is not loading. It does not work so far.

Comment: Working fine for me... Do share executable snippet....

Comment: working fine https://jsfiddle.net/nu4ngh31/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like everything works great in your code.

If you want to **reset** the background-color on every click you can set it to `''`:

```js
$(".switcher span").click(function(){
      var galleryIndex = $(this).index();
      $('.wrapper .gallery').css('background', '').eq(galleryIndex).css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="switcher">
    <span>Switch 0</span>
    <span>Switch 1</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gallery">GALLERY 0</div>
    <div class="gallery">GALLERY 1</div>
</div>
```